# How to sort the cards in each hand from the card values first and then the suits in C?

Tags: c, sorting

I want to sort the 5 cards from each hand, by sorting by the card value first (from Ace to King) and then the card suit (from Hearts, then Diamonds, then Clubs and lastly Spades), but it doesn't work. How would you be able to do it successfully?

code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

/* handy typedefs */
typedef unsigned char card;
typedef unsigned char pairs;

/* arrays for the names of things */
static char *suits[4] = {"Hearts","Diamonds","Clubs","Spades"};
static char *values[13]= {"Ace","Two","Three","Four","Five","Six","Seven",/
                          "Eight","Nine","Ten","Jack","Queen","King"};
static char *colour[2]= {"Black","Red"};
int compareface(const void* c1,const void *c2);

int main()
{
 card deck[52][24],*deckp;
 int s, c, a;

 for(s = 0; s < 4; s++)//for filling a deck of 52 cards
 {
   for(c = 0; c < 13; c++)
   {
    if (s== 0 || s== 1)
    sprintf(deck[s * 13 + c], "%s of %s", values[c], suits[s]);
    else
    if (s== 2 || s== 3)
    sprintf(deck[s * 13 + c], "%s of %s", values[c], suits[s]);
        }
    }

    for(a = 0; a < 52; a++)
    {
    printf("%s\n", deck[a]);
    }

    int hand,cd,winner;
    int irand;

     srand(time(NULL));       /* seed the random number generator */

    for (hand=0;hand<5;hand++)
    {   
     printf("Hand %i:\n",hand+1 );
      for ( i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      irand = (rand() % 52);
      //   qsort(deck, 52, sizeof(int), compareface);
      if ( (irand >= 0) && (irand <26))
      printf(" %s, is Red.\n ", deck[irand]);
      else
      if ( (irand >= 26) && (irand <52))
      printf(" %s, is Black.\n ", deck[irand]);
      }
     }
    /* determine the winner and print it */
      return 0;
    }

      void shuffle(card deck[52])
    {
    int i,rnd;
    card c;

    for(i=0;i<52;i++)
    {
    /* generate a random number between 0 & 51 */
     rnd=rand() * 52.0 / RAND_MAX;
     c = deck[i];
     deck[i] = deck[rnd];
     deck[rnd] = c;
       }
     }

    int compareface(const void* c1, const void *c2)
    {
     /* This function extracts the two cards face values
     and returns 1 if cd1 > cd2, 0 if cd1 == cd2, and
     -1 otherwise. The weird argument types are for
      compatibility with qsort(), the first two lines
       decode the arguments back into "card".
      */
      card cd1,cd2;
      cd1=*((card*) c1);
      cd2=*((card*) c2);

      cd1= (cd1&0x1e)>>1;
      cd2= (cd2&0x1e)>>1;

      if (cd1>cd2)
        return 1;

      if (cd1==cd2)
        return 0;

        return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Shay Gold said, it is simpler to use an `int` for the value of the cards. Edit: His method is described at the end of this post, his method seems to automatically make a suit sort inside a value sort.

You can define values from 0 to 51:

- cards of value < 26 are black and the others are red, you can get the colour with `value / 26`.
- cards of value < 13 are Hearts, with value >= 13 and < 26 are Diamonds, with value >= 26 and < 39 are Clubs, with value >= 39 and < 52 are Spades. You can get the suit with `value / 13`.
- the value(from 0 to 12) of a card can be got with `value % 13`.

If you want the Ace to be higher than the King, just move it in the table `values` at the 13th place.

You can have a look at the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

/* handy typedefs */
typedef unsigned char card;
typedef unsigned char pairs;

/* arrays for the names of things */
static char *suits[4] = {"Hearts","Diamonds","Clubs","Spades"};
static char *values[13]= {"Ace","Two","Three","Four","Five","Six","Seven",
                          "Eight","Nine","Ten","Jack","Queen","King"};
static char *colour[2]= {"Black","Red"};

int compareface(const void * c1, const void * c2);
int comparesuit(const void * c1, const void * c2);
void shuffle(int deck[52]);

int main()
{
  int deck[52];
  int s, c, a, i, j;


    for(a = 0; a < 52; a++) //for filling a deck of 52 cards
    {
      deck[a] = a;
      printf("\n%s:", colour[ deck[a] / 26 ]);
      printf(" %s of", values[ deck[a] % 13 ]);
      printf(" %s", suits[ deck[a] / 13 ]);
    }

    int hands[5][5],h,cd,winner;
    int irand;

    srand(time(NULL));       /* seed the random number generator */

    // shuffle the deck before to get the hands:
    shuffle(deck);
    j = 0;
    for (h=0;h<5;h++)
    {
      printf("\nHand %d:",h+1 );
      for ( i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        hands[h][i] = deck[j];
        printf("\n    (%s)", colour[ hands[h][i] / 26 ]);
        printf(" %s of", values[ hands[h][i] % 13 ]);
        printf(" %s", suits[ hands[h][i] / 13 ]);
        j++;
      }
    }
    // sort the cards by card value:
    for (h=0;h<5;h++)
    {
      qsort(hands[h], 5, sizeof(int), compareface);
    }
    // print the hands:
    for (h=0;h<5;h++)
    {
      printf("\nHand %d:",h+1 );
      for ( i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("\n    (%s)", colour[ hands[h][i] / 26 ]);
        printf(" %s of", values[ hands[h][i] % 13 ]);
        printf(" %s", suits[ hands[h][i] / 13 ]);
      }
    }

    // sort the cards by card suit:
    for (h=0;h<5;h++)
    {
      qsort(hands[h], 5, sizeof(int), comparesuit);
    }
    // print the hands:
    for (h=0;h<5;h++)
    {
      printf("\nHand %d:",h+1 );
      for ( i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("\n    (%s)", colour[ hands[h][i] / 26 ]);
        printf(" %s of", values[ hands[h][i] % 13 ]);
        printf(" %s", suits[ hands[h][i] / 13 ]);
      }
    }

    /* determine the winner and print it */
      return 0;
}


void shuffle(int deck[52])
{
    int i,rnd;
    int c;

    for(i=0;i<52;i++)
    {
    /* generate a random number between 0 & 51 */
     rnd=rand() * 52.0 / RAND_MAX;
     c = deck[i];
     deck[i] = deck[rnd];
     deck[rnd] = c;
    }
}

int compareface(const void * c1, const void * c2)
{
  const int cd1 = *(const int*)c1;
  const int cd2 = *(const int*)c2;
  if(cd1 % 13 > cd2 % 13) return 1;
  if(cd1 % 13 == cd2 % 13) return 0;
  return -1;
}

int comparesuit(const void * c1, const void * c2)
{
  const int cd1 = *(const int*)c1;
  const int cd2 = *(const int*)c2;
  if(cd1 / 13 > cd2 / 13) return 1;
  if(cd1 / 13 == cd2 / 13) return 0;
  return -1;
}
```

About the sorting problem, do you want to have two differents sorts, or have a sort inside another sort ? For example, if you want to have a suit sort inside a value sort, you can replace the second qsort call in the precedent code with, I'am not sure of this algorithm, but it seems to work:

```
for (h=0;h<5;h++)
{
  for ( i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    for(j = i+1; j < 5; j++) {
      // if the cards have the same values but a suit higher than the following card,
      // then exchange the cards:
      if( (hands[h][i] / 13 > hands[h][j] / 13) && (hands[h][i] % 13 == hands[h][j] % 13) ) {
        c = hands[h][i];
        hands[h][i] = hands[h][j];
        hands[h][j] = c;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you want a values sort inside a suit sort:

```
for (h=0;h<5;h++)
{
  qsort(hands[h], 5, sizeof(int), comparesuit);
}

for (h=0;h<5;h++)
{
  for ( i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    for(j = i+1; j < 5; j++) {
      // if it is the same suit and the card have a higher value
      // then exchange the cards:
      if( (hands[h][i] % 13 > hands[h][j] % 13) && (hands[h][i] / 13 == hands[h][j] / 13) ) {
        c = hands[h][i];
        hands[h][i] = hands[h][j];
        hands[h][j] = c;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Shay Gold method:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

/* handy typedefs */
typedef unsigned char card;
typedef unsigned char pairs;

/* arrays for the names of things */
static char *suits[4] = {"Hearts","Diamonds","Clubs","Spades"};
static char *values[13]= {"Ace","Two","Three","Four","Five","Six","Seven",
                          "Eight","Nine","Ten","Jack","Queen","King"};
static char *colour[4]= {"Red","Red","Black","Black"};

int compareface(const void * c1, const void * c2);
void shuffle(int deck[52]);

int main()
{
  int deck[52];
  int s, c, a, i, j;


    for(a = 0; a < 52; a++) //for filling a deck of 52 cards
    {
      deck[a] = a;
      printf("\n%s:", colour[ deck[a] % 4 ]);
      printf(" %s of", values[ deck[a] / 4 ]);
      printf(" %s", suits[ deck[a] % 4 ]);
    }

    int hands[5][5],h,cd,winner;
    int irand;

    srand(time(NULL));       /* seed the random number generator */

    // shuffle the deck before to get the hands:
    shuffle(deck);
    j = 0;
    for (h=0;h<5;h++)
    {
      printf("\nHand %d:",h+1 );
      for ( i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        hands[h][i] = deck[j];
        printf("\n    (%s)", colour[ hands[h][i] % 4 ]);
        printf(" %s of", values[ hands[h][i] / 4 ]);
        printf(" %s", suits[ hands[h][i] % 4 ]);
        j++;
      }
    }
    // sort the cards by card value:
    for (h=0;h<5;h++)
    {
      qsort(hands[h], 5, sizeof(int), compareface);
    }
    // print the hand:
    for (h=0;h<5;h++)
    {
      printf("\nHand %d:",h+1 );
      for ( i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("\n    (%s)", colour[ hands[h][i] % 4 ]);
        printf(" %s of", values[ hands[h][i] / 4 ]);
        printf(" %s", suits[ hands[h][i] % 4 ]);
      }
    }


    /* determine the winner and print it */
      return 0;
}


void shuffle(int deck[52])
{
    int i,rnd;
    int c;

    for(i=0;i<52;i++)
    {
    /* generate a random number between 0 & 51 */
     rnd=rand() * 52.0 / RAND_MAX;
     c = deck[i];
     deck[i] = deck[rnd];
     deck[rnd] = c;
    }
}

int compareface(const void * c1, const void * c2)
{
  const int cd1 = *(const int*)c1;
  const int cd2 = *(const int*)c2;

  return cd1 - cd2;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It will be easier if you give each card a numeric value and to save this value in the deck array.
Now, one way to do that will be:
1 = Ace of spades, 2 = Two of spades ... 13 = king of spades, 14 = Ace of Hearts and so on, but it is harder to order.

Another way, however,  will be:
0 = Two of diamonds, 1 = Two of clubs, 2 = Two of hearts, 3 = Two of spades, 
4 = Three of diamonds and so on.

If you use this way the `(card number) / 4` gives you the value (with an offset) and `(card number) % 4` gives you the suit.

More over, `return (card1 number) - (card2 number)` gives you the comparison function you  wanted.

Hope I helped

Comment: how can you do that in C code?

Comment: would you use qsort for the C problem?

Comment: Break it down to simple functions: 1. CardValue - gets a card number and returns its value. 2. CardSuit gets a card value and returns its suit. 3. the shuffling should be similar to what you did. the comparison function I wrote above. qsort sounds right.